# ahah_helper or ctools for ahah in Drupal 6?

Tags: 6, forms, chaos-tool-suite, ajax

The excellent ahah_helper module (http://drupal.org/project/ahah_helper) improves the core ahah functionality to the point where it works quite nicely.

Ctools (http://drupal.org/project/ctools), seems to bypass the core functionality totally, offering its own brand solution.

Ctools seems to be quite a bit more complicated, needing more complexity to deal with no-js situations : http://drupal.org/node/1025448#comment-4196882

Where as ahah_helper seems much cleaner/simpler to deal with : http://drupalcode.org/project/ahah_helper.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/ahah_helper_demo.module

So.

Which is better?
Which is more like the implementation in 7 (so we only learn once)?

Answer (score 1):

You're better of using ctools in D6. Also all the ctools ajax implementation is whats in Drupal 7 known as the [Ajax Framework](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--ajax.inc/group/ajax)